# Should users be allowed to delete their questions right away?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just finished answering a question and clicked Post. The user deleted his question, so I get no credit for my effort.

I'm not allowed to accept my answer to a question I raised for another 10 hours, but Johnny Jump Jomp can delete his.

In all likelihood, Johnny found the answer for himself.

Comment: What's the question? 10kers can vote to undelete it if it was actually a good question

Comment: Aside @mcandre: welcome to Meta!  Since you have (well over) 200 rep on SO, you can get a free one-time bonus of 100 rep here.  Just go to your profile, then the accounts tab, and manually disassociate/reassociate your SO account with this one.  This will actually work on any SE site.

Comment: Popular Demand: That didn't work, or maybe it takes a day to for the change to propagate.

Comment: perhaps, it's been a while for me.  Do you see it at the top of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Answer (score 1):

Accepting an answer and Deleting a question are fundamentally different operations.

**Accepting an answer** is done when a particular answer showed you what needed to be done, or pointed you in the right direction. The reason that this can't be done for a certain period of time (can't remember right now, will edit) is that accepting usually discourages other answers, and we want many users to try to answer, just in case one of the newer answers is stellar and even better than the original.

**Deleting a question** is meant to be done when the question was a mistake or does not belong on SO. For that reason, self-deletion can be done immediately. It may be that the question was mistakenly posted, or fundamentally flawed, or the problem doesn't exist. It could be for **any number** of reasons which we do not access to.

Not allowing you to accept an answer immediately only serves to cause users to return later. Forbidding users from deleting their mistakenly posted questions could have negative consequences for them.

It also follows the principle of "Always allow users to undo".

Comment: `"Always allow users to undo"` with the exception of awarding bounties (which is right) and (automatically) turning posts CW (which is irreversible despite the potential of human error or misunderstanding what CW actually means).

Comment: @Tobias, Absolutely correct. There are situations where undo is impossible or unfeasible.